# how to prepare a query to json postgresql field in php

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I am having a problem creating a query in PHP to retrieve a json value from a postgresql database.

The problem is within the json WHERE clause of the following simple query

```
select * from json_data where jsonfield ? 'roottag';
```

if i use the PDO prepare:

```
$query->prepare($sqlSelect);
```

PDO will translate the ? (postgres json operator to see if the json field starts with a specific tag) to $1.

How do i write a sql statement similar to the one above to be used within php PDO?

Comment: How about read the docs first? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Apologies, i did read that page, but have not understand how to avoid that prepare() translates the "?"

Answer (score 2):

To safe other people some time: **A PATCH IS ON THE WAY!** (at the time of writing)

see: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1967